# Maximo Assets: Last sync date

Tags: cron, timestamp, gis, integration, maximo

I have GIS assets that are integrated/synced with Maximo via cron tasks.

I want to query the Maximo `assets` table to get the last sync date.

This is not to be confused with the `changedate` column, which I believe updates after any change, including manual changes to the asset (ie. not necessarily due to a sync).

**How can I query assets' last sync date using SQL?**

*Maximo 7.6.1.1; Oracle 12c.*

Comment: Related documentation here:   [Creating cron tasks that run automation scripts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mt.doc/autoscript/t_cron_task_scripts.html)

Comment: I think the documentation on creating cron tasks that run automation scripts is only related in that you could use a cron task + automation script to write your own sync process that date-stamps each sync'd record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if I could do something like this?

1. Create a LASTSYNCDATE field in the Maximo ASSETS and LOCATIONS tables.
2. Configure the JSON mapping so that the LASTSYNCDATE field is populated with `&SYSDATE&`.

- For each record, if the sync was successful, then the LASTSYNCDATE field would be populated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a guaranteed way to do this unless you extend / build into the sync process something to record the last sync date somewhere. If the GIS sync process used "normal" integration, Object Structures, queues and so on, then you might be able to configure and join to Message Tracking. But (unless someone cares to correct me) it doesn't, so it's up to you to capture what you care about.

Comment: If you configure Message Tracking then they are stored in `maxintmsgtrk`. But given my historical knowledge of Spatial's sync process and how LDAPSYNC still works, I don't think Message Tracking will help you. I rewrote LDAPSYNC with an autoscript, similar to the cron task documentation you linked to, to make it do what we want.

Comment: Based on your diagram, I would add a "lastsyncdate" attribute to all your objects that sport feature classes and populate it with the current system date (MXServer.getDate()) via an integration automation script which would be automatically invoked pre-MBO as part of step 3. If you wait until the MBO part of step 3 and have an autoscript with an object launch point, you would have to analyse the stack trace or etc to confirm the source of the change was the MIF /  the sync process, which seems to me not as good of practice.

Comment: Ha. To answer the "normal" question, yes, the diagram shows use of MIF and queues and so I expect it to be normal. The OOTB LDAPSYNC process skips the MIF, queues and MBOs, at least as of 7.6.0. Since the Spatial sync uses the MIF, you could do the Message Tracking thing, but my preference would still be for a `lastsyncdate` attribute set via an integration autoscript.

Comment: It looks like a good thing to try, at least. The "Property" part of "Source Property" makes me wonder if your value will be processed as intended.